# What is the right path to partials html in AngularJS app under Grails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, asset-pipeline

I am working on a project using a Grails server for the back-end (using asset-pipeline as resource manager) and I would like to use AngularJS as my front-end manager.

I am trying to use `ngRoute` to reload my page content, but the problem is that I can't figure out where to put my partials files nor what path I should set as `templateUrl`

Here is my code:

grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require grails-angularjs
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'test.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

I already tried to put my test.html in web-app/partials and set the `templateUrl` to `static/partials/test.html`, nothing better. Whatever I am using, I always end up with a 404 not found

Does anyone know what my tree should look like and what path should I set in my config?

Comment: You could use [Angular template asset pipeline plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/angular-template-asset-pipeline).

Comment: You can see in the error the path that is trying to get the template and use that.

Comment: @dmahapatro I already tried that, and there seem to be compatibility problems because a lot of errors are poping at runtime
First line is WAR packaging error: No signature of method: static asset.pipeline.AssetHelper.getAssetPathsByPlugin() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: @JsIsAwesome the error path that is provided only tells me where it cannot find the template i'm asking, but it doesn't tell me where it is in my server's tree

Comment: There are a few possible variations (the plugin mentioned above being one of them)  As a simple start, you should be able to put your file in `web-app/partials/test.html` and refer to it using  `partials/test.html` as the `templateUrl`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Eventually I put the views in assets/javascripts/views

This is my manifest (application.js):

```
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-route/angular-route
//= require angular-resource/angular-resource
//= require angularapp
//= require_tree views
//= require_self
```

Then I have this for the route configuration:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    controller: 'GioController',
    templateUrl: '/angular-asset-bower/assets/views/view.html',
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
}); }])
```

You can check out the complete example project here: https://github.com/gioper86/angular-asset-bower